# How to put in one repository two codes from 2 platforms

Tags: github, push

How can I push on github in one repository the code of a project, when backend code is on visual studio and front end code on visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

We do that on a few projects by using subfolders. In the root of the repo we have a `Back` and a `Front` folder. The Back has a .NET Core webapi project and the Front has a React app.

It works nice for us as the same team maintain both codebases and we usually need to change both every time we do a new feature anyway.

It also works nice from a build/deployment point of view since we do a full build and deploy both projects on every merge to the main branch.

Your mileage may vary. I probably wouldn't to this unless the same team is responsible for both codebases.